# laravel log files showing wrong time even though I have edited timezone in app.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My log files timestamps are alls wrong by 2hours.

I have edited my apps timezone to:

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Stockholm',
```

but I still get the wrong time when using `Log::error()`

I am running Laravel through Valet if that matters.

Comment: Have you ran `php artisan config:clear`?